# Can Mule cxf:proxy client component handle streaming of big data

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, mule

My application is supposed to handle large data (~100MB), I am trying to send ~80MB of payload using `<cxf:proxy-client>` component via `InputStream`. I don't see any activity in my logs from the point where proxy-client is configured.

I've tried sending 8MB data and that works fine. Am wondering if `Mule3.3.0` can handle that.